# Why does the output of this request add spaces?

Tags: python

```
print("Blah: [",blah_url,blah,"]<br>", file=f)
```

Output:

```
Blah: [ http://blah/Pages/Revision.aspx?projectId=541511cd-86bf-46fc-ae70-aec46e6030c7 blah ]<br>
```

The additional space after the open bracket "[" and before the close bracket "]" shouldn't be there.

It should look like this:

```
Blah: [http://blah/Pages/Revision.aspx?projectId=541511cd-86bf-46fc-ae70-aec46e6030c7 blah]<br>
```

I have confirmed there are no extra spaces in the data being supplied as the input.

Comment: Yes, the space *should* be there: that's how the `print` function is designed and documented.

Answer (score 0):

The print function automatically adds spaces between each of the parameters. Try this (it overrides the adding of spaces):

```
print("Blah: [", blah_url, blah, "]", file=f, sep="")
```

or this (passing it in as one parameter):

```
print("Blah: [" + blah_url + blah + "]", file=f)
```